# ASP.NET, Best way to accomplish task on my webform?

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for advice on the best way to accomplish the following:

I have three tables - Reports, Activities, Notes.

Activities and Notes are related to the Reports table. (For each report, there are many activities and notes.)

I need to create a webform that will allow the user to create a new report and then create many activities and notes within that report. All data needs to be written to the appropriate tables in the database.

I'm having trouble with the logic here. I've tried using multiple formview controls on the same page, programmatically updating tables, etc etc etc. I can't seem to find a good way to accomplish this relatively easy task. Any advice out there?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet and explain how you've attempted it? I don't get the multiple FormView part?

Comment: Yeah, I think this question needs some more thought. It's hard to determine exactly what you are asking here.

Comment: I don't have the code at my disposal right now. In your opinion, if you were creating this from scratch, how would you design the webform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to design this, I would use two separate pages. The first page would be an overview page with a grid of all reports. The grid would show some simple basic info (reportid, name, dates, note/activity count, etc). This page would also feature search options to filter the grid. I would link the record on the grid that will redirect them to a "details.aspx?id=XXX" page. I would also have a create new report button that also redirected to the details page, but without the querystring params.

The details page would have 3 tabs. Tab 1 would be "Report Info". Tab 2 would be "Activities". Tab 3 would be "Notes".

The details page would handle both insert and updating of reports. If the "id" querystring doesn't exist, then your user wants to insert a new Report, so in this case, you hide tabs 2 and 3. You would also not perform the databind functions. Upon saving tab 1 (the report), you run an insert method. Once successfully inserting the report, redirect them to details.aspx?id=NEWID where they can continue to add activities/notes.

If the "id" querystring does exist, then your user is in edit/update mode. In this case, all 3 tabs are shown. A save to tab 1 (Report), would do an update on the reports table.

The Activities and Notes tab should be laid out however best the data is to be displayed. If the data is just a single string, I would display a form to insert a new activity/not and then below, display existing notes/activities in a list format using the repeater or datalist.

Hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ricketts, exactly the guidance I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble with the query string (details.aspx?id=NEWID). After creating the report, I need to pass "ReportID" as the query string, correct? ReportID is the primary key of the table and is set to identity/auto increment. I assume I need to trap this value when the record is inserted into the table, but how?

Comment: It depends on how you work with data. If you are working with ADO.NET, you'll do it one way, if you are working in LINQ, you would do it a different way. Do a search on here for "get id of inserted record" and you'll find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about **[MultiViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ek2z7fh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

---

**Advantages**

1. You can keep your all three requests in the same page.
2. It will reduce your round trips. So use `Server.Transfer`.
3. Removes Query String headache.
4. Using multiple pages will require Routing/Rewriting functionalities

---

**DisAdvantages**

1. It will become cumbersome.
2. Maintenance cost will be high.

---

It should be used if you have your requirements clear and small.